# Scientific notation only for specific numbers of a dataset's column

Tags: r

I need to format numeric columns of a data frame showing scientific notation only when the number is less than 0.0001. I have written the following code where `format` function has been used. The problem with this code is that it transforms all numbers.

Any suggestion?

```
col1 <- c(0.00002, 0.0001, 0.5689785541122558)
col2 <- c(3.5, 45.6546548788, 12585.5663)
tab <- cbind(col1, col2)
tab <- as.data.frame(tab)
format(tab[1], digit = 1, nsmall = 3)
```

Comment: Do any of the answers resolve the issue, mbistato?

Answer (score 3):

You could `apply` on both margins `1:2`.

```
as.data.frame(apply(tab, 1:2, \(x) format(x, digits=1, nsmall=3)))
#    col1      col2
# 1 2e-05     3.500
# 2 1e-04    45.655
# 3 0.569 12585.566
```

Or if you want to format just one specific column:

```
transform(tab, col1=sapply(col1, format, digits=1, nsmall=3))
#    col1        col2
# 1 2e-05     3.50000
# 2 1e-04    45.65465
# 3 0.569 12585.56630
```

Important just is, that each element is formatted individually.

Here another way using `replace`.

```
tab |> 
  round(5) |>
  (\(.) replace(., . < 1e-4, format(.[. < 1e-4], digit=1, nsmall=3)))()
#      col1        col2
# 1   2e-05     3.50000
# 2   1e-04    45.65465
# 3 0.56898 12585.56630
```

Comment: Can we make it with ```ifelse``` too? If yes - can you add it to your answer? ;) I tried to do it, but somewhere made a mistake ;( Imagine, we have a big table and don't know, where are elements <0.0001

Comment: @manro See update using `replace` which is what you probably had in mind.

Answer (score 3):

**1) dplyr** Define a vectorized format and use that in mutate/across:

```
formatv <- function(x, ...) {
  mapply(format, x, scientific = abs(x) < 0.0001, ...)
}    

library(dplyr)
tab %>% mutate(across(, formatv, digit = 1, nsmall = 3))
```

**2) Base R** or with only base R (formatv is from above)

```
replace(tab, TRUE, lapply(tab, formatv, digit = 1, nsmall = 3))
```

or

```
replace(tab, TRUE, formatv(as.matrix(tab), digits = 1, nsmall = 3))
```

or if you have a small number of columns do each individually

```
transform(tab,
  col1 = formatv(col1, digits = 1, nsmall = 3),
  col2 = formatv(col2, digits = 1, nsmall = 3))
```

**3) collapse**  formatv is from above.

```
library(collapse)
ftransformv(tab, names(tab), formatv, digit = 1, nsmall = 3)
```

**4) purrr** map_dfc in purrr can be used.  formatv is from above.

```
library(purrr)
tab %>% map_dfc(formatv, digit = 1, nsmall = 3)
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the Base R one.

Answer (score 1):

```r
lapply(tab, \(x) ifelse(abs(x) < 0.0001, format(x, scientific=TRUE), format(x, scientific=FALSE)))
# $col1
# [1] "2.000000e-05" "0.0001000"    "0.5689786"   
# $col2
# [1] "    3.50000" "   45.65465" "12585.56630"
```

You can reassign back into the frame if you'd like with `tab[] <- lapply(tab, ...)`. Note that all columns are now `character` not `numeric`.

This can be done perhaps *slightly* more efficiently by working on the `matrix`, now no need for `lapply`:

```r
tab <- cbind(col1, col2)
ifelse(tab < 0.0001,
       format(tab, digit=1, nsmall=3), 
       format(tab, digit=1, nsmall=3, scientific=FALSE))
#      col1          col2         
# [1,] "2e-05"       "    3.50000"
# [2,] "    0.00010" "   45.65465"
# [3,] "    0.56898" "12585.56630"
```

which can then be converted into a frame.